# Using image as gesture recognizer in Swift/Xcode, image coming up nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I just got finished going through the big nerd ranch iOS programming book and started my first 'project'. I'm trying to use a UIImageView as a button but my image is coming up as nil and I cannot figure out why. I'm new at this, so any help, or even just identifying any parts of this code that don't make sense is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ImageScreenViewController: UIViewController {
    @ IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    // set up images 
    let picture1 = UIImage(named: "picture1")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set image on screen
        imageView.image = picture1
    }

    // set up gesture recognizer
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(count(_:)))
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func count(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapped the picture")
    }
}
```

note, picture1 is in Assets.xcassets.

Comment: you can access the image outlet after view has been loaded to view hierarchy. so you need to add gestureRecognizer in viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some explanation for your question

```
encodeWithCoder(_ aCoder: NSCoder) {
    // Serialize 
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // Deserialize 
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //You used
}
```

To add a Gesture you actually do not need to implement coder here as These are being used to store the state

Check following example

1- ImageView is being taken from storyBoard 
2- myImage is being Added using code

Now , Storyboard initially implants serialise and deserialise mechanism 
Thus imageView is a property being added from storyboard so no need for coder there

```
import UIKit

class ImageVC: UIViewController {


    @ IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    // set up images
    let picture1 = UIImage(named: "cc")

    //ImageView programmaticlly
    var myImage = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // set image on screen
        imageView.image = picture1

        //setting properties and frame
        myImage.image = picture1
        myImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        self.view.addSubview(myImage)

        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(count(_:)))
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    // set up gesture recognizer
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        //adding gesture
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(count(_:)))
        self.myImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        self.myImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    @objc func count(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapped the picture")
    }

}
```

As if you implement above Algo It won't crash , as For Properties being added from storyboard can directly be accessed in didload or willAppear as we never going to remove them from superview so indirectly its serialised

Second case - myImage - Added Programmatically can also be removed from superView and added again Thus can be serialised means need to be

Comment: thanks, this was very helpful in understanding what was going on in the code

Comment: Welcome, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

you can add tapRecongnize in viewDidload because in init method imageview not initialize and return nil so that you can use like this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            imageView.image = picture1

            let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(count(_:)))
            self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
            self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var image: UIImage?

@IBOutlet weak var imageChoisie: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    imageChoisie.image = image // from Segue
    
    // Click on Image
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(count(_:)))
    self.imageChoisie.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    self.imageChoisie.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func count(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    //print("tapped the picture")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // back previous screen
}
```